# Is there a way to encrypt my traffic in foreign networks?

Tags: security, vpn

I will be staying in a hotel network for a while and I don't like the idea of someone wiresharking me.

Is there any VPN software allowing me to encrypt my traffic? Something similar to TOR browser, but with less hops, because I don't want my internet speed to get affected too much.

Comment: What exactly is `VPM software`?  Most operating systems have the built-in capabilities to connect to a VPN service if thats what your asking.

Comment: Well, I think it’s pretty clear the OP meant to write VPN. Everything else simply doesn’t match the context. Seeing how m and n are next to each other...

Answer (score -2):

If you want to encrypt your traffic you will need to have a server that knows how to read the encrypted messages and a a client that sends the encrypted messages.

Since most softwares will not read your encrypted messages you will need to create a a server and a client.
Make your client send encrypted messages to your server.
Store your server on an outside network (such as at your home).
If you want to send encrypted message to another server you would now make your server decode the encryption and then send the information to the 3rd party server (such as internet explorer).
 Now your server will need to send the information, that internet explorer sent back to your server, to your client.
The chart would look like this...

```
CLIENT............................................SERVER
   |...................[AUTHENTICATE]................|
............................../\
............|_>____[SEND ENCRYPTED MESSAGE]
.......................[DECRYPT MESSAGE].............|
...............[SEND COMMAND TO SOFTWARE]__________<_|
...[SEND ENCRYPTED software response to client]____<_|
..[Decode the response and memory hack the software to set the response]
```

This is as clear i can possibly be with this, people have dedicated there entire careers to ensure security of their clients, so don't expect yourself to be able to do this over night.

I recommend you use 
C++ for encryption (has some advantages over c#)
C# for the Server & client

There really is no other way for you to have encryption in this scenario and it might be out of your league to attempt.

If your within the United Nations you could use a smart phone with 3g and broadcast to your laptop. (this would be even more secure if you have this luxury)

-Also,
If the op meant Virtual Machine software not VPM,
Note that VM software would not secure anything.
If the op mean Virtual Private Network then here is a ling to what a VPN is,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

Comment: Note that the isp could inspect your encrypted messages, but if your encryption is done correctly you should be fine.

Comment: This answer does not seem to fit the question.  The author does not appear to be knowledgeable in C++ or programming at all.  Even if he is you should recommend solutions that already exists instead of rolling out his own solution.

Comment: superuser isn't really for programming, that's stackoverflow.

Comment: The user does not seem to be knowledgeable in anything on this subject, he asked about network security and i gave the best possible solution. it is not expected he know how to use C# or C++, i only supplied how it is done.